# How to convert cURL PUT syntax to correct PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, put

I am struggling to get the Qualtrics PUT API to work using PHP.

The cURL syntax is:

```
    curl -X PUT -H 'X-API-TOKEN: yourtokenhere'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "status": "active",
    "lastName": "ExampleLastName",
    "password": "uwillneverguess",
    "firstName": "ExampleFirstName",
    "userType": "UT_1234567890AbCdE",
    "accountExpirationDate": null,
    "permissions": {
        "controlPanel": {
            "accountPermissions": {
                "accessApi": {
                    "state": "off"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}' 'https://yourdatacenterid.qualtrics.com/API/v3/users/UR_1234567890AbCdE'
```

I need this to work in PHP. I am trying to update the password only. I would appreciate any help as I've been trying for a while with no success.

Qualtrics doesn't provide any example PHP code but the following additional information might help:

Request Headers

```
Accept: */*
X-API-TOKEN: yourtokenhere
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-type: application/json
content-length: 24
```

Request Data

```
{
    "password": "Password1"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a sample php example based on your curl example.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://yourdatacenterid.qualtrics.com/API/v3/users/UR_1234567890AbCdE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n    \"status\": \"active\",\n    \"lastName\": \"ExampleLastName\",\n    \"password\": \"uwillneverguess\",\n    \"firstName\": \"ExampleFirstName\",\n    \"userType\": \"UT_1234567890AbCdE\",\n    \"accountExpirationDate\": null,\n    \"permissions\": {\n        \"controlPanel\": {\n            \"accountPermissions\": {\n                \"accessApi\": {\n                    \"state\": \"off\"\n                }\n            }\n        }\n    }\n}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Api-Token: yourtokenhere";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Hi Abhinav, thanks for your quick response, I appreciate it.
I just tried this (with the actual token and UR_xxx) and I get the following error:
Error:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: add one more line to ignore ssl warning and error : 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);`

Comment: beside that there is one nice PHP library which is majorliy used for API calls : http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: try these `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much Abhinav, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Abhinav Verma for the answer:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://yourdatacenterid.qualtrics.com/API/v3/users/UR_1234567890AbCdE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n    \"status\": \"active\",\n    \"lastName\": \"ExampleLastName\",\n    \"password\": \"uwillneverguess\",\n    \"firstName\": \"ExampleFirstName\",\n    \"userType\": \"UT_1234567890AbCdE\",\n    \"accountExpirationDate\": null,\n    \"permissions\": {\n        \"controlPanel\": {\n            \"accountPermissions\": {\n                \"accessApi\": {\n                    \"state\": \"off\"\n                }\n            }\n        }\n    }\n}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Api-Token: yourtokenhere";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```